# Set height to container in Gridview.builder

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working with the following code and got struck. I wanted to set the height to the container so that the images which are displayed inside it will be fitted well. In the present condition the image gets fitted inside the container and it does not look good. I have used a grid view to display images from firebase.

```
class Catview extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CatviewState createState() => _CatviewState();
}

class _CatviewState extends State<Catview> {
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> subscription;
  List<DocumentSnapshot> wallpaperList;
  final CollectionReference collectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection("pubg");

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = collectionReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      setState(() {
        wallpaperList = datasnapshot.documents;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription?.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return (SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: wallpaperList != null
            ? GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                ),
                itemCount: wallpaperList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  String image = wallpaperList[index].data['image'];
                  return Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Image.network(
                      image,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              )
            : Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add preperty `childAspectRatio` in SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount. `childAspectRatio` as aspectRatio, because in gridview can't support height dan width. Unless you use this library Staggered Grid View . https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view.

this is example if you use gridview without library.

Example:

```dart
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 2,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4,
                  childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                ),
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use the childAspectRatio property present in the GridView.builder class

```
GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  childAspectRatio: 2/3,
                ),
....
```

I like to use the popular aspect ratios present in photography which are the 2/3 (2:3) or the 3/4 (3:4) to get the kind of look I normally like.

If you want a wider width in relation to the height, use the aspect ratio in reverse (i.e. 3/2 or 4/3) depending on your need.

Hope it helps! :)